# HTML Grid Column Hide when zoom

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a zoom style like on stackoverflow. When you zoom in the important content gets centered and takes 100% of the width and everything on the sides are hidden.

Is this achievable by pure CSS or do I need to use JS? My idea would be to check per JS the screen size and render dependant on this which div class I render.

Comment: They use media queries to un-float the sidebar `@media screen and (max-width: 816px) { html.html__responsive.html__unpinned-leftnav #sidebar { float: none; clear: both;    margin: 0 auto;}` - It's not hidden, it just moves to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

The terminology you are looking for is "responsive design".  It involves treating everything on the page as cells that fall below each other into a column as the screen size gets smaller.  This can be done in many ways, all css, no javascript required.  The best way that I have found is to use flexbox for layouts.  The second best, and in fact a fallback for older browsers that don't support flexbox, is to use display: inline-block.  I typically ignore any browsers that don't support either flexbox or inline-block, but if you have to support very old cruddy browsers, you can use floats for this purpose.  Media queries should also be mentioned, which allow you to change your css rules at breakpoints.  I try to avoid these as much as possible, because they don't allow for continuous flow as a page's size changes, but sometimes they are necessary if you can't find any other way.  However, flexbox normally handles everything without needing them.  Css grid is also worth mentioning, though I have not found it to be very useful for responsive design, but it's worth looking into.

There are very few cases where I have found javascript to be necessary for layout.  One of these is if you want the font size to be a function of the container dimensions.  Normally though, I'd just stick to css for layout.